# Вносить свою лепту в редакцию

Tags: обсуждение

на основном сайте стекОверФлоу =>

Иногда редактируют вопрос, и меняют построение фраз, опечатки✅, удаляют ненужные моменты по типу запретных слов✅ либо просто помогают правильно поставить вопрос✅...

Но сегодня, когда я читала свой вопрос, будто и не я спрашиваю. Может я соглашусь, что я йода, но это моя манера общения. Ведь человек спрашивает и дает акцент на что-либо в своем предложении.

Есть ли смысл в данном случае менять/переставлять фразы, писать внутри вопроса малеьнкие/большие буквы итп...

Я не говорю об опечатках, но вот для меня например важно дать акцент на первую фразу и не ставить ее в конец => речь об => *Правильно ли я создала запрос....*

и **насколько верно, если нет критических моментов (ругани, дефект картинки), редактировать вопрос ?**

[ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1552819/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*p.s. Глеб мне симпатичен, и к редакции вопроса нет вопросов(и более чем уверенна, что он хотел сделать еще лучше вопрос), но это уже не мой вопрос, будто шапочку надели серенькую, как у всех... обязательно точку там, тут большую букву, как будто прям окр...или какие то нормы. Иногда красиво, когда как у художника. Это не код, это вопрос технический не по грамматике тем более*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149869/discussion-on-question-by-dev18-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.